# Euclidean distance between documents

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

For each function, I am manually adding another case. Can this be somehow shortened?

Case and function names are the same. For example, the `Euclidean_Distance` case calls the `Euclidean_Distance` function, and all the functions take the same parameter.

```
double dblDistance = 0;

switch (csSettings.enDistanceMetricBetwenDocForHC) {
 case csPublicSettings.enDistance_Metrics_Between_Documents_For_HC.Euclidean_Distance:
  dblDistance = csStringDistanceAlgos.Euclidean_Distance(
   csTf_Idf_Generator.Return_Word_List_Of_Document(vrFirstdoc, csSettings),
   csTf_Idf_Generator.Return_Word_List_Of_Document(vrSecondDoc, csSettings)
  );
  break;
 case csPublicSettings.enDistance_Metrics_Between_Documents_For_HC.Squared_Euclidean_Distance:
  dblDistance = csStringDistanceAlgos.Squared_Euclidean_Distance(
   csTf_Idf_Generator.Return_Word_List_Of_Document(vrFirstdoc, csSettings),
   csTf_Idf_Generator.Return_Word_List_Of_Document(vrSecondDoc, csSettings)
  );
  break;
 case csPublicSettings.enDistance_Metrics_Between_Documents_For_HC.Manhattan_Distance:
  dblDistance = csStringDistanceAlgos.Manhattan_Distance(
   csTf_Idf_Generator.Return_Word_List_Of_Document(vrFirstdoc, csSettings),
   csTf_Idf_Generator.Return_Word_List_Of_Document(vrSecondDoc, csSettings)
  );
  break;
 case csPublicSettings.enDistance_Metrics_Between_Documents_For_HC.Maximum_Distance:
  dblDistance = csStringDistanceAlgos.Maximum_Distance(
   csTf_Idf_Generator.Return_Word_List_Of_Document(vrFirstdoc, csSettings),
   csTf_Idf_Generator.Return_Word_List_Of_Document(vrSecondDoc, csSettings)
  );
  break;
}
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Comment: It's called polymorphism. Any time you want to clean up a switch, you should be thinking about several classes that implement an interface. You'd still need a switch I think, but you could tuck it away in a factory instead of the client code. Separation of concerns & all that.

Comment: You should do some reading on strategy pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak i checked but i dont see how that decreases amount of code to be written in above case

Comment: @Vogel612 ty for answer. i think my question really clear. can above code be written in a shorter way. it is very simple cases and these cases calls functions.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. I strongly suggest you add your Reflection-based solution as an alternative answer. Be sure to explain it's benefits over the current solution

Comment: @Vogel612 alright

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to map the calculator for each distance type.

First, construct this dictionary before calling the method with the 'switch' statement. I do not know the signature of your methods, so I'm assuming that they're taking and returning ints. I've shortened the names to make it easier to read.

```
    var calculators = new Dictionary<int, Func<int,int,int>>();
    calculators[DistanceType.Euclidean] = StringDistanceAlgos.Euclidean_Distance;
    calculators[DistanceType.Squared] = StringDistanceAlgos.Squared_Euclidean_Distance;
    calculators[DistanceType.Manhattan] = StringDistanceAlgos.Manhattan_Distance;
    calculators[DistanceType.Maximum] = StringDistanceAlgos.Maximum_Distance;
```

You can now replace the switch statement with this:

```
    if (calculators.contains(distanceType))
    {
        var calculator = calculators[distanceType];
        dblDistance = calculator(
            Return_Word_List_Of_Document(vrFirstdoc, csSettings),
            Return_Word_List_Of_Document(vrSecondDoc, csSettings));
    }
```

The above code checks and calls the distance calculator if it exists.

If you have new distance types, you only need to add it to the dictionary above.

Comment: so we can put functions into dictionary and call them? this looks nice let me try

Comment: works great very decent solution indeed. I solved problem with reflection but this is also very good and i didn't know before this :D upvote and best answer

Answer (score 6):

Quick remarks:

- [DO NOT use Hungarian notation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx): `dblDistance`.
- Is `csPublicSettings` a class name? If so, it [should be PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72.aspx). (I'm guessing the "cs" is a prefix indicating this is a class -- if so: see above.)
- Same for `enDistance_Metrics_Between_Documents_For_HC`, plus: [DO NOT use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric characters.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) Ditto for `Euclidean_Distance`
- `csTf_Idf_Generator`, `Return_Word_List_Of_Document`, `vrFirstdoc`: same rules as above.
- `enDistanceMetricBetwenDocForHC` contains a typo: `Betwen`.

---

Considering that all these methods return a "distance" and that all of them take the same parameters, I'd suggest a base class `DistanceCalulator`, which is then implemented by a `EuclideanDistanceCalulator` etc.

- `DistanceCalulator` has a constructor that takes `vrFirstdoc`, `vrSecondDoc` and `csSettings`
- and calls `csTf_Idf_Generator.Return_Word_List_Of_Document()` to fill two `protected` properties,
- and there's an `abstract` method `Calculate()` which is implemented differently in `EuclideanDistanceCalulator` etc. which returns the distance.

Then you'll get a method which will use a `switch` to return the appropriate `DistanceCalulator`:

```
private DistanceCalulator GetDistanceCalulator(csPublicSettings.enDistance_Metrics_Between_Documents_For_HC enumName,
    SomeClass vrFirstdoc,
    SomeClass vrSecondDoc,
    SomeClass csSettings)
{
    switch (csSettings.enDistanceMetricBetwenDocForHC) 
    {
        case csPublicSettings.enDistance_Metrics_Between_Documents_For_HC.Euclidean_Distance:
            return EuclideanDistanceCalulator(vrFirstdoc, vrSecondDoc, csSettings);
}
```

And then you can do:

```
dblDistance = GetDistanceCalulator(enumName, vrFirstdoc, vrSecondDoc, csSettings).Calculate();
```

There's always going to be a switch, but this way at least you're not repeating too much logic. You might even want to put those four parameters in a class and pass that class instead.

---

Note that this is basically example code, just to give you an idea in which direction to go. Once you start copy-pasting code, consider it a sign you're doing something wrong and you should move things to a separate method.

The point is not so much to "shorten" code, but to avoid repeating/copy-pasting code blocks and to make it easier to maintain. By using this base class you can easily add another `DistanceCalculator` without having to copy-paste half a dozen lines and making some minor adjustments. Instead you add a new class and focus on the one important piece: the contents of the `Calculate()` method.

Comment: ty for suggestions. any solution to the question?

Comment: well i solved the problem with reflection. any bad side of it? and with reflection i just have to write 1 line code :)

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG yes, there's a bad side, you are using magic strings to get the right function for the calculation, reflection should always be the last resort solution. You should have shown us more code, I am pretty sure it can be solved better then a switch, dictionary or reflection, you are doing it wrong somewhere else.